# Calculation of a line integral over a simple elliptic region

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, line-integrals, greens-theorem

**Problem**: Assume that $C$ is the positively-oriented elliptic curve $x^2 +4y^2 = 4$. What is the value of $\oint_C (x^3 + 2y)dx + (4x-3y^2)dy$?

**Attempt**: I say we do this the Green way; that is, using Green's theorem: First we put the ellipse in standard form $x^2/4
 + y^2 = 1$, then $$\oint_C (x^3 + 2y)dx + (4x-3y^2)dy=\iint \bigg(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(4x- 3y^2)-\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(x^3 + 2y)\bigg)dxdy=\iint_C (4 - 2)dxdy = 2(\text{ellipse area})= 4\pi.$$
However, as usual there is a solution manual that disagrees with me, saying that $\pi$ is the value of the integral not $4\pi$. What do you think?

Much obliged!

Comment: I can't immediately see anything wrong with your approach, and calculating the integral directly without Green still gives $4\pi$. Are you sure you've copied the problem statement correctly?

Comment: Checked it also. Everything seems correct.

Comment: Thanks for reading. Yes. I double checked!

Comment: A lousy solution manual then ...

Comment: That would be my guess. You could check if the textbook you're using has an online errata, maybe it's been fixed already.

Comment: Of course! Between the 3 of us, it's not their first error :)

Comment: If the ellipse was $x^2 +4y^2 = 1$, their answer would be correct. As it is $x^2 +4y^2 = 4$, your answer is correct.

Comment: Yes. However the RHS is clearly 4. no two-ways about it.

Comment: Yes , they wrote one thing and solved for something else. Looks like that.